# What happened to Lucy after the end of Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood?

Tags: video-games, assassins-creed

I have this question on the *Assassin's Creed* story plot. I want to know what happened to Lucy after Desmond stabbed her at the end of *Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood*?

Presumably she died but what was the reason that the Apple made Desmond do that? More so in *Assassin's Creed III*, I noticed that Desmond mentions Lucy was a traitor? How's that so?
Did I miss something? I mean I have only played the PC version of games.

Comment: spoiler alert!!

Comment: She went on to found the Assassins Creed Sisterhood, of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't miss anything, this isn't really elaborated upon in *Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood*, *Assassin's Creed: Revelations*, or *Assassin's Creed III*.  It is largely explained in a DLC for *Revelations*, [*The Lost Archive*](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_Archive).  In *The Lost Archive*, it's revealed that Lucy was a triple agent.  She was a Templar who spied on the Assassins, who thought she was an Assassin spying on the Templars.  Juno had Desmond kill her, as Lucy would end up interfering with Juno's plans.  It's unclear if you've finished *Assassin's Creed III* from your question, so I won't spoil the ending, but if Lucy had stuck around and betrayed the group, it would have prevented the ending from playing out the way it does, which is why Juno killed her.

So, between the DLC and the events of AC3, it's clear why Lucy was killed.

Comment: Oh I guess we really miss a lot without the downloadable contents. Unfortunately I have a slow internet connection and can not get them. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's said in AC3 that Desmond feels a lot of grief over what happened, and that she was buried in Tuscany or close-by (but Desmond was unconscious at the time).

Answer (score -2):

Actually another thing is **she just died**. Juno was trying to put Desmond under **extreme shock**, and she say this to be the only way.This can bee figured out by simple looking at **patent 16** as comparison.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Does Juno ever say she killed Lucy to put Desmond under shock? How can this be figured out by looking at Subject 16?

Answer (score -3):

She was a sleeper agent for absturgo and Juno made it clear in revelations that it needed to be done but SPOILER Desmond dies at the end of three tissue the world and after it is unknown who you are like in rogue and blackflag

Comment: technically this is an answer, but I'm not clear how it includes anything not already in the accepted answer?